# Series - convergence and divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the following series diverge or converge?

$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2\times3^2} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \frac{1}{2\times5^2} + \frac{1}{6^3} $$

I am not able to find a closed form thus I cant use any tests to determine.

Comment: What is the pattern in the denominator?

Comment: Compare with $\sum{1\over n^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try thinking of it as two series added together:

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2(3)^2} + \frac{1}{2(5)^2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \frac{1}{6^3} + ...$$

And remember that the sum of a series converges if and only if each series converges.

Comment: And, fortunately, you're not being asked what that second series sums to...

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong. $1-1/2+1/3-1/4+\cdots$ converges but $1+1/3+1/5+\cdots$ and $-1/2-1/4-1/6-\cdots$ individually do not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Your series is equal to:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2(2k-1)^2}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(2k)^3}\right)$$
Because both exists.